# next.js My app doesn't return an error when input field is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, error-handling

I've created a currency converter app. My app accepts number as input and works well. However, when user types something other than a number or leaves the input field empty, my app does nothing. I want it to return an error notice clarifying that providing a number is required.

This is my current code but it doesn't work. It even doesn't throw an error on the console but tries fetching as if number is provided.

**input.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Input = ({ dropdown, onChange, label, symbols }) => {
  const arrOfSymbols = Object.keys(symbols);
  arrOfSymbols.sort();

  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const inputValue = e.target.value;
    console.log('Input Value:', inputValue);
    // Check if the input is empty or not a number
    if (inputValue.trim() === '' || isNaN(inputValue)) {
      // Set the error state
      setError('Please enter a valid number.');
      console.log('Error:', 'Please enter a valid number.');
    } else {
      // If the input is valid, clear the error state
      setError('');
      // Proceed with the provided onChange callback
      onChange(inputValue);
    }
};
```

**Input field on input.js:**

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter the number you want to convert" className="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl" onChange={handleInputChange} />
```

**Fetching part of index.js:**

```
  // FETCH
  const convertCurrency = () => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/api/convert",
      params: { convertFrom, convertTo, amount },
    };

    axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
       const { data } = response;
       setConvertedAmount((data.result));
       setError(null); // Clear any previous errors
     }).catch(function (error) {
       console.error(error);
       setError('An error occurred during conversion.'); // Set an error message
     });
 };
```

What my console throws when I click on Convert button (triggers convertCurrency function above) while input field is either blank or non-numeric:

> GET http://localhost:3000/api/convert?convertFrom=ANG&convertTo=ANG&amount=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first mistake you are making is using [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to determine whether the input is a number or not. As you can read following the above link, it's to be used to detect if a value equal [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), not any number.

I would use a regular expression to avoid conversion before validation, because `e.target.value` comes as a string even if the type of the input is `number`:

```js
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
const inputValue = e.target.value;
console.log("Input Value:", inputValue);
const isNumberRegX = /^\d+$/;

// Check if the input is empty or not a number
if (!isNumberRegX.test(inputValue)) {
    // Set the error state
    setError("Please enter a valid number.");
    console.log("Error:", "Please enter a valid number.");
} else {
    // If the input is valid, clear the error state
    setError("");
    // Proceed with the provided onChange callback
    onChange(inputValue);
}
};
```

Second, you would want to use `onInput` instead of `onChange` (which triggers only after the input looses focus, and on Safari it doesn't if a non-number value is in the field):

```
<input
    type="number"
    placeholder="Enter the number you want to convert"
    className="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl"
    onInput={handleInputChange}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've made these changes and now I can see error on the console. Not when I click on Convert button but while typing something other than a number into the input field. I also made it visible on the client side. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

To check if a value is a real, finite number, use Number.isFinite()
Very simple, very elegant.

Number.isFinite() returns true only if the value is a number that's not infinity or NaN. It's a straightforward and reliable way to ensure you're working with a valid number.

For more details, check out the MDN docs: [Number.isFinite() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite)